# C++/CLI ^String to unsigned char

Tags: parsing, visual-c++

Im using Visual Studio 2013 I need to get the selected item from a ComboBox,

unsigned char zona = char::Parse(ComboBoxExcluyeZonaZona->SelectedItem->ToString());

The Content of ComboBoxExcluyeZonaZona is numeric, ex: 1,2,3,4 ....

The char::Parse is returning "".

How do I properly convert the ^String to the unsigned char?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is `String^` (the `^` is at the end). [Overview of Marshaling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)

Comment: But, if you are using C++/CLI but *not* interfacing with "pure" C++, stick with the C++/CLI .Net types. And are you wanting an integer? Then use the integer parsing. But if you want only one character (so can't be `10`?), then just get the first character of the string using `[]`.

Comment: I tried doing s[0], still returned "", i need to use unsigned char (BYTE) because i'm comunicating with a modem and a small electronic device with limited memory